# Trendline not printing

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, charts, trendlines

I have many pages with similar graphs and data tables to print. And there is one page that does not print the trendline in the graph. I reloaded the file and tried printing it which worked out, then i tried to PDF it but again it does not print the trendline in the line graph. Ofcourse i tried to reopen the document again without result. I also tried to adjust the Y axis slightly without result.

I really need to PDF the pages, i cant wrap my head around the fact it prints all 32 pages correctly except this one. It is not different then any other graph of the same category on the other pages. There are 2 more graphs on the page that print and PDF fine. I tried two PDF creators, "cutePDF" and "PDF creator".

I work around would be to scan that single page that did print normally, but this is kind of "hacky" and does not solve the problem.

Comment: Both cutePDF and PDFCreator use the same postscript driver, so with those two there would be no difference. Could you zoom in the resulting PDF to see if you **do have** a very thin line? Color and Line-width could be a factor here.

Comment: @Rik Since it's not printing either it probably does not even matter. I do not have a very thin line, the line contrasts very well and is the same as in all the other similar graphs on the other pages.

Comment: Maybe you could try recreating the graph. Weird that after reloading the file it did print correctly. Is it still printing that page correctly now (to a real printer) or has that also stopped working? And does it show in the "print preview" onscreen?